# PanelGrid column classes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have problem in `columnClasses` tag of `h:panelGrid`

I have a panel grid with two columns:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="rp1,rp2">

    <h:message id="pass1Msg" for="pass1"/>
    <h:inputSecret id="pass1" value="#{accountBean.pass1}" required="true">
        <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="4"/>
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="passwordMsg"/>
    </h:inputSecret>
    <p:watermark for="pass1" value="Enter new password..."/>

    <h:message id="pass2Msg" for="pass2"/>
    <h:inputSecret id="pass2" value="#{accountBean.pass2}" required="true">
        <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="4"/>
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="passwordMsg"/>
    </h:inputSecret>
    <p:watermark for="pass2" value="confirm password..."/>

    <h:outputLabel value=""/>
    <h:commandButton id="resetBtn" action="#{accountBean.doReset}" value="Reset"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And here is the `rp1,rp2` classes:

```
.rp1 {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: red;
    font-family: yekan;
    font-size: small;
}

.rp2 {
    width: 200px;
}

.rp2[type="text"]{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Problem is that the `rp2[type="text"]` not rendered.

But `.rp1` and `.rp2` are works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css class **rp2[type="password"]** instead of **rp2[type="text"]** . Hope it helps.